# Xamarin IOS can't initialize visibility plugin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin project with an ios and a android app. In both I want to use the MvvmCross Visibility Plugin. On Android it generated the proper bootstrap file and usage works fine. On iOS I created a own bootstrap file, but I always get the following message:

```
MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Could not find plugin loader for type MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader
```

Also I tried to call the plugin loader manually in the InitializeLastChance:

```
MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
```

But this leads to the same exception.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Just to confirm you have included the `Visibility` plugin nuget package in the iOS project and the reference is without warning and the dll appears in the output directory?

Comment: Yes, the nuget package is added and I can see the MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.dll and  the MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.iOS.dll in the bin folder. Also  I can't see any warnings regarding this.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Perhaps a version miss match, are all the `Visibility` plugin's on the same NuGet version?

Comment: Yes. All at 5.2.1

Comment: I have the issue with plenty of plugins by the way. i registered the file plugin for example manually.